# Android: ViewModel has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger2, viewmodel

Возникает такая ошибка (MainViewModel has no zero argument constructor). Не могу найти в чем причина, буду благодарен за помощь.

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class space.rodionov.currencyconverter.main.MainViewModel
  /* bla bla bla */
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<space.rodionov.currencyconverter.main.MainViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
 at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
 ... 39 more
```

ViewModel начинается так:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: MainRepository,
    private val dispatchers: DispatcherProvider
) : ViewModel() {
 
    // body
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
// etc
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCurrencyApi() : CurrencyApi = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(CurrencyApi::class.java)

    //@Singleton
    //@Provides
    //fun provideMainRepository(api: CurrencyApi): MainRepository = DefaultMainRepository(api)
    //закоменчено 10.06

    @Singleton
@Provides
fun provideDispatchers(): DispatcherProvider = object : 
    DispatcherProvider {
    override val main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Main
    override val io: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.IO
    override val default: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Default
    override val unconfined: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Unconfined
}
}
```

MainRepository:

```
interface MainRepository {
    suspend fun getRates(base: String) : Resource<CurrencyResponse>
    }
```

DefaultMainRepository

```
@Singleton // добавил 10.06
class DefaultMainRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: CurrencyApi
) : MainRepository {

    override suspend fun getRates(base: String): Resource<CurrencyResponse> {
        return try {
            val response = api.getRates(base)
            val result = response.body()
            if (response.isSuccessful && result != null) {
                Resource.Success(result)
            } else {
                Resource.Error(response.message())
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Resource.Error(e.message ?: "An error occurred")
        }
    }
}
```

Правки 10.06

Добавил интерфейс:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface AppModuleBinds {
    @Binds
    fun bindMainRepository(bind: DefaultMainRepository): MainRepository
}
```

- также добавил аннотаци @Singlteon к DefaultMainRepository и убрал соотвутствующую зависимость в AppModule.

Comment: Как получаете ViewModel и есть ли у этой активити или фрагмента `@AndroidEntryPoint` аннотация? ps. `DefaultMainRepository` наверняка с `@Inject` аннотацией, сделайте `@Binds` метод, зачем `@Provides` то...

Comment: Да, ```@AndroidEntryPoint``` есть, ViewModel получаю ```by viewModels()``` (добавил в вопрос). Да, ```DefaultMainRepository``` - с ```@Inject```-ом. насчет ```@Binds``` не понял. Он требует чтобы функция была ```abstract```, но я не могу сделать ее таковой оставив ```= DefaultMainRepository(api)``` (тело)... Я по видеоуроку делал. В Hilt пока до конца не разобрался..

Comment: Добавьте ещё зависимости, которые вы подключиили

Comment: По поводу `@Binds`, сделайте интерфейс `@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) AppModuleBinds` например и добавьте туда метод `@Binds fun bindMainRepository(bind: DefaultMainRepository): MainRepository`, `@Singleton` добавьте на класс DefaultMainRepository, а provideMainRepository удалите. Иначе весь смысл от Inject на DefaultMainRepository пропадает

Comment: К сожалению это тоже не помогло, причем ошибка та же самая что и была. (Я дописал снизу вопроса правки, которые попробовал.)

Comment: про binds это было просто небольшое замечание, а не фикс. Проблема, скорей всего, в неправильных зависимостях (старая версия, не так подключили, либо забыли нужную зависимость подключить) https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup, смотрите раздел Using Hilt with Kotlin и Hilt Gradle plugin

Comment: Ну и так же должен быть ещё свой Application с @HiltAndroidApp (и Application 
 должен быть прописан в манифесте)

Comment: Поменял версии Hilt dependencies на более старые и все заработало. Не знаю где точно, но где-то видимо в них было несоответствие, буду разбираться где. Спасибо за помощь.